# wild card match on request headers for nginx

Tags: if-statement, nginx, header, wildcard

I am using nginx as a proxy server to send the requests to backend pool members .

I have a header -- Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="21ad608c-8e00-4c0c-8a06-5ed1280e9532"
The boundary value in the header changes all the time.

How can I do a header check for only "Content-Type: multipart/form-data;" value and route the requests to the backend. when I do a print of $http_content_type value , everything including boundary value is getting printed . I am not able to do an if check on just " Content-Type: multipart/form-data; " value .

Can I put a wild card in the nginx config like -- "multipart/form-data; * "  to pass the if loop ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

An Nginx wildcard? Yes, sort of, via a regex:
`if ($http_content_type !~ '^multipart/form-data;') deny-the-request`

This means that the Content-Type must start with `multipart/form-data;`. After that, any `boundary=...whatever...` is allowed.

Complete example:

```
  location /-/upload-public-file {
    limit_except POST OPTIONS {
      deny  all;
    }

    if ($http_content_type !~ '^multipart/form-data;') {
      return 406;  # status code Not acceptable
    }
```